# Is there a better practice to manage the instancing of classes?

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, instance, n-layer

So to give some context I'm making a project for an architecture class, and I'm trying to debug some problems with my WebService, for this I created a library class that mimics the functioning and logic of the WebService. But I find that I need to change a lot of code every time I find some bug and I was thinking that there could be a better and smarter way to resolve this that I simply don't know yet.

This is the way I handle most of my functions and methods:

```
private void btnLogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntegracionLogin auxLogin = new IntegracionLogin();
    //NegocioLogin auxLogin = new NegocioLogin();
    Login aLogin = new Login();
    String nombre = this.txtNombreUsuario.Text;
    String contrasena = this.txtContrasena.Text;
    try
    {
        String respuesta = auxLogin.IValidaLogIn(nombre, contrasena);
        //String respuesta = auxLogin.ValidaLogIn(nombre, contrasena);
        Console.WriteLine("dfasf" + respuesta);
        if (respuesta.Equals("Cliente"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estimado Cliente, Bienvenido");
            MenuCliente pantCliente = new MenuCliente();
            pantCliente.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (respuesta.Equals("Empleado"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estimado Empleado, produce plata");
            MenuEmpleado pantEmpleado = new MenuEmpleado();
            pantEmpleado.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error de logIn :  " + ex + "\n");
        MessageBox.Show("UwU!" + "\n" + "No se encuentra en el sistema," + "\n"
                            + "si cree que fue un error contacte con el administrador.");
    }
    aLogin.Dispose();
}
```

About the code I just showed you, this is the line I'm concerned about:

```
IntegracionLogin auxLogin = new IntegracionLogin();
```

This method is sort of simple as it doesn't need to instance a lot of other classes, but when I try to debug or integrate the WebService layer, I need to change hundreds of lines every time... So I thought this is really inefficient and maybe there could be a better way to handle this.

Comment: I meant to ask if there is a way to maybe instantiate in a method all of these lines (refer to second code block) so that I only need to modify that method instead of 200 to 1000 lines that are mostly equals... I thought programming was about trying to minimize redundancy. If you could can you offer me insight as if the question is not clear to what I intend to convey? or if I misunderstood the general idea? @TaW (I feel like you are mocking me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: IDK why I lose my time using this site, I'm not in the mental state where I can take much criticism in a good light, anyhow I was just asking something trying to be as polite and clear as possible. But thankfully someone directed me into the into something called "Factoring" witch is what I needed.

Comment: Whereever you go, always make sure to read the rules of the site! Your post break pretty much all rules and recommendations. Do read the help pages! Good luck! Hint: SO is not just there to help you but to collect useful questions and answers into a large archive.  Re-read you post and ask yoursel how much of it will be useful for furtue readers!! All the rest (aka 'fluff' ) should not be there.

Comment: @TaW so... yeah you were right, I was using the site wrongly. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you are having this problem I suggest you to look into using a "Factoring" approach, it can be better explained by looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612284/calling-a-method-on-every-instance-of-a-type-in-c-sharp)

It should help to reduce the amount of lines needed to modify when trying to debug and changing the layers used in an n-layered approach.